# current page name in Liferay

Tags: liferay, portal

`themeDisplay.getLayout().getName(themeDisplay.getLocale());`
is returning the key that entered such as "label.key.account" not the key value mapped to.

**Any ideas? Please let me know, if I need to have the properties in a specific properties file.**

Thanks,
Sri

Comment: `themeDisplay.getLayout().getName(themeDisplay.getLocale())` this code will return string which is entered as name against locale while you edit page/layout. If you have entered some key then it will return key only, I believe. You have to provide translated name itself.

Comment: Yes you are correct. keys are entered , so it is returing keys only. Thanks for the answer.